# Single-statement VB.NET If-block executed when condition is false? VS 2005 bug?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, if-statement, visual-studio-2005

I was wondering if you have encountered this bug before:
On a single-line of IF, the condition returns FALSE but then the execution proceeds to the TRUE part.

Am I doing something wrong here? `retries` and `errorTolerance` are both of type `Integer` and from the screenshot below, `retries` is less than `errorTolerance`. But still it executes  the statement for the `True` part.

[image: The statement goes to the TRUE part when the condition is False]

This has been screwing up my program so what I did was place the `Throw New Exception` in another line and close with `End If` and it works.

I guess my question will be what's wrong with my previous code?

Comment: Does the problem exist *without* debugging? (I have a vague recollection of a .. similar? .. SO post a long while ago.)

Comment: Could it be a multithreading or re-entrant code issue?

Comment: Yes, it still goes to the True part of the statement without putting a breakpoint.

Comment: Are "errorTolerance" and "retries" simple variables? They're not functions are they?

Comment: @SSS This is just single-threaded. It's working on a web service that is quite buggy, so I have to put an error tolerance. I put the single thread to sleep, so I could pause the operation, and call the web service again until the `retries` exceeds the `errorTolerance`

Comment: Nope, they are just primitive types - both of type `Integer`

Comment: Try moving the if statement to just under the retries increment?

Comment: Side note: Throwing a *new* exception like that is a bad idea - you lose all of the stack trace information, any inner exceptions, other useful properties, etc. Either have a plain `Throw` (which will reuse the existing exception), or throw a new exception with a specific message and pass `ex` as the `InnerException`.

Comment: @SSS moving it up still produces the same result :(

Comment: Have you tried a Build->Clean Solution followed by a Build->Full Rebuild?

Comment: @Steve yes. Multiple times, just to be sure it wasn't using any old DLL. Still same result. I have the same problem years ago, but I just worked my way around it (creating a full IF...END IF statement)

Comment: Do you have option strict On?

Comment: I suggest you turn it on. It may not help this specific issue it wont hurt

Comment: It may be a bit heavy duty but loading teh compiled code into something like Refactor (http://www.reflector.net/) would enable you to see what the code looks like after decompiling. It should hopefully allow you to see what the compiler has done to that line and allow you to understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't afford not to continue coding, I resorted to the regular `If...End If` block. Visual Studio and the compiler runs the code perfectly, although it left me wondering why this expression stymied VS.

Answer (score 1):

Disable optimization to make sure that there is a clear linear correspondence between lines of code and the corresponding compiled instructions.

If this is release mode compilation, and `retries` is just a local variable going out of scope, the compiler may have just optimized away storing of the incremented value in the register that holds `retries` initially, but still use that register when inspecting the expression.

To confirm this, you will see `retries` and `errorTolerance` to have the same values in release mode, and `retries` having a value larger by one after recompiling in debug mode.  Inspect the variables individually as you step through the lines.

Comment: The line `retries+=1` is just where the breakpoint is... The active line of code in the screenshot is the `throw` after the if.

Comment: @Chris - Hm, thank you.  Deleted the incorrect first half of the answer and expanded the second part that I still think is valid.

Comment: hi. Sorry I restructured my code to the regular `If...End If` block since I can't afford not to continue with my code. But the `retries` variable is declared in the start of the `Sub`, and this happens even when `retries=1` and `errorTolerance = 10`. And the QuickWatch still show the expression as `FALSE`.

Comment: @DevMonster - Does the exception actually get thrown?  (You can configure the debugger to break on any CLR exception.)

Comment: Yes. That's how I found out the problem - it was prematurely throwing the exception, considering the error tolerance is 10, and with a `Threading.Sleep` of 1 second, it should occur after 10 seconds minimum, but it was thrown almost instantaneously.